# How do we promote our site?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

One of the [7 essential questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/) is how can we promote our site.  There are [some generic suggestions from the StackExchange team](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/a-recipe-to-promote-your-site/), but probably there are things that we can do that are specific here, as well.

Note that this probably [our biggest problem](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4451/science-fiction) at the moment - our views are quite low and the number of questions asked is low as well (presumably there are highly dependent, i.e. more views means more questions, and more questions means more views).

Answer (score 7):

I thought the [card/board games site](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33/how-do-we-promote-our-site) had a couple of interesting ideas:

- Adding a signature link if you participate in on-topic forums.
- Questions about new works.  We don't want to just pre-fill questions, so they'd have to be real questions, but this does bypass the 'found on Wikipedia' issue (i.e. if we have the content first).
- Conventions.  This seems like a reasonably fertile ground for potential users.  They suggest "stump the stack" (i.e. pose a difficult - but real - question, and see whether the users can answer it), as well as general promotion.  Does anyone here attend cons?

Answer (score 2):

I was wondering whether I could contact some popular fantasy blog writers. So far I haven't done it, because it seems too much like spamming. Are there any policies on it?

Comment: you end this answer with a question (an interesting one at that). Why not post this as a new question?

Comment: It's not SE policies you should worry about, but the policies or mores of the site you'd be posting on. The ideal way to advertise would be if someone asks a question somewhere else and you link to the answers here. An unsollicited mention will be considered spam in many communities.