# What happens at the end of the beta?

Tags: discussion, site-statistics, beta

At [area51's stat page for scifi](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4451/science-fiction-fantasy), 2 of the important parameters - Questions per day and Visitors per day are marked worrying. It also says that the site's progress will be evaluated in 12 days from now(i.e. around 12 April). So any idea what this entails? Is there a chance that the site may be stopped or something? How can users contribute to this evaluation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Nothing

Ours stats are comparable with [board and card games](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5220/board-and-card-games) which is in beta since 162 days.

So, we will probably get this mention :

> This site will remain in beta indefinitely so it can grow; we will continue to evaluate its site statistics and overall health.

Answer (score 6):

That date on Area 51 is not the end of the beta, it's when the site is first evaluated. Most sites are in fact not ready at this point, usually because they don't have enough traffic. They remain in beta until the traffic improves.

This site is no exception. We're very far from having a critical mass. If we lose momentum, the site may be closed. But I don't think we've sunk that low. We have a good core that we can grow on.

You can help:

- Ask good questions. (And write good answers, too.)
- [**Promote the site**](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340/how-do-we-promote-our-site). Tell your friends about it. Link to it on your blog or social sites. If someone asks a question that's been covered here, point them to it.

Comment: Promoting sites is hard.  Is there some way we can track if our promotions are having any effect at all?

Comment: @Glen Wheeler: If our promotions are being effective, we will see an overall boost in traffic. Beyond that, it will be pretty hard to draw specific lines, although if we start linking all over facebook, we should see a spike in facebook refers.

Comment: @Glen: You can get a badge — [Announcer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/badges/54/announcer), [Booster](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/badges/55/booster), [Publicist](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/badges/56/publicist) — for generating a lot of views on a specific question (when people use the “short permalink” that contains your user ID). I don't think there's any public data for the site as a whole.